# Finding location of company from website

Tags: excel, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

First, thanks for the help I just started learning to code a few days ago, so I appreciate the help!

so basically I have a list of company urls and want to find where they are located. What I’ve been thinking of doing was using urllib2 and BeautifulSoup to get all of the text from the urls and then searching through that text to find either California, Massachusetts, new york, etc and having it print out whichever one it finds into a document I can put into excel. So far I've written the code below which gives me a set of text, but I have no idea how to search it, how to do it with multiple urls, or how to print that information into an Excel-readable format.

Thank you!

```
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


links = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.coolcomposites.com/')
html = links.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
locations = ["Boston", "MA"]
file_text = soup.get_text()
print (file_text)
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If yes, please up-vote and mark as answer so your question can be closed.. Happy coding, cheers mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the `locations` list and check if each entry exists in `file_text`.

```
for loc in locations:
  if loc in file_text:
    print ("Found location")
  else:
    print ("Location not found")
```

**Watch Out**

**1. Capitalization**

Stick with one representation of `locations`. Either everything is lower case, upper or upper first then lower etc. Point is, don't mix it up because it the above implementation is not case sensitive so `MA != ma != Ma != mA`.

So say you choose lower case for `locations`, convert `file_text` to lower case as well.

**2. Mid point detection**

In `locations`, you included *MA*. This will be detected as well in any text that consists of *MA* regards of its location. Think of possible ways to overcome this problem.